# AVG picked this up as a virus - but won't let me clean it. Help!

Tags: virus

"D:\i386\Apps\App002216\wtsetup-english.exe:\$JN\gateway\fate-oem.exe";"Trojan horse Generic19.BIBS";"Infected"

Is this a virus? There are 173, most are associated with something called wildtangent that is not installed on my computer. The virus error indicates that the file size is bigger than the archive size limit, so I can't clean it. Someone help please!

Answer (score 2):

Thats a false positive, Wild Tangent (while annoying) is not a virus. Its finding these files on the recovery partition on your hard drive. I would ignore warnings from the D drive, and report it to your AV vendor.

Comment: Confirmed, "Fate" is a wildtangent game...http://games.wildtangent.com/fate/